# Why my items are overflowing out of my LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this [image: LinearLayout] containing **eight** programatically added items.

But as you guys can see, the items are overflowing out of the screen to the right side.

There's my LinearLayout code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/items"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/segmento"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">
```

The ImageView's inside the LinearLayout are added programatically with `{ImageView}.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(184, 184));`
and then `items.addView({ImageView})`

Just to add the info, `"@+id/segmento"` is invisible in the screenshot.

Thank you! :D

Comment: Well there is not enough room to display more...?

Comment: Alright. Then I need to add the excessive items to another line. How I achieve that?

Comment: If you know how many to fit in a line, create another line set below the previous line. Just line it up as needed.

Comment: I'm searching for a more dynamic solution. Like some XML configuration to when there are too many items in a line, put the next ones in a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear Layout does not support overflowing to the next line.
You can only divide the available space over the children, so that each one would get small enough to fit all of them next to each other. (for this, look into the `weight` attribute on the layout params).

However, what you ***really*** want, is called [FlexBoxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). This has been ported to Android not to too long ago by Google and does exactly what you want.

Comment: That's it!! Now it's okay! Thank you for your response! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the layout width to match_parent. As your orientation is set to horizontal and the width is set to wrap_content, it might not be taking the screen size into consideration.

Comment: Same result. My items aren't going automatically to a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using MATCH_PARENT for width and WRAP_CONTENT when adding image view programmatically:

```
{ImageView}.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            ,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
items.addView({ImageView})
```

This will ensure it works across devices with different screen sizes too. If you hardcode the width and height it may not work across all devices.

Also within your layout, chane your linear layout to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Tried that. Same result.
What I need is: `foreach LinearLayout line { if(line.Items.Count == 5): item.line += 1 }` or some XML configuration to when items are taking all the space, automatically put the next items to another line.

Comment: hmm, did you try flipping the width and height?
as in, set change width to wrap_content and layout to match_parent ?

Comment: Tried it right now. Unfortunately, same results. I think I'm using the right Layout type to make that, but I wonder if using another sort of Layout will give me a good result (?)

Comment: you could try using RelativeLayout. There you can specify which elment should go above,below, left, right etc